# How to update object in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript

I have an indexed list of `users` in the JS object (not array). It's part of the React state.

```
{
    1: { id: 1, name: "John" }
    2: { id: 2, name: "Jim" }
    3: { id: 3, name: "James" }
}
```

What's the best practice to:

1. add a new user { id: 4, name: "Jane" } with id (4) as key
2. remove a user with id 2
3. change the name of user #2 to "Peter"

Without any immutable helpers. I'm using Coffeescript and Underscore (so _.extend is ok...).

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This is what i would do

- add: `var newUsers = _.extend({}, users, { 4: { id: 4, ... } })`
- remove: `var newUsers = _.extend({}, users)` then `delete newUsers['2']`
- change: `var newUsers = _.extend({}, users)` then `newUsers['2'].name = 'Peter'`

Comment: This is the right answer. Use extend to create a new object, then mutate.

Comment: I agree, but in "change" case we also have to copy the modified user's object, like this: var newUser = _.extend({}, users['2'], { name: 'Peter' }); var newUsers = _.extend({}, users, { 2: newUser });

Comment: @pierrepinard_2 good point, that makes shouldComponentUpdate better for the component that shows individual users.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not using Flux, you use this.setState() to update the state object.

```
delUser(id) {
    const users = this.state.users;
    delete users[id];
    this.setState(users);
}

addChangeUser(id, name) {
    const users = this.state.users;
    users[id] = {id: id, name: name};
    this.setState(users);
}
```

Then you can execute your test cases with this:

```
addChangeUser(4, 'Jane);
addChangeUser(2, 'Peter');
delUser(2);
```

Comment: Your `addUser` methods will update the object with key `id` rather than adding an object with key `4` as specified by OP. `changeName` has the same problem.

Comment: You're right. Guess I typed faster than I could think. I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you're using ES2015 (ES6) you could do `this.setState({ [id]: { ... });`.

Comment: Please note, these methods are not immutable. You are mutating `this.state` directly. Seems OP wants to stay immutable "without any immutable helpers"

Comment: Objects in JS are are passed by reference so you're mutating the original ones here @KellyKeller-Heikkila

Comment: these are mutating the state object. correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/36650760/1536309

Answer (score 2):

Apart from  _.extend you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for storing `user`

```
let user = new Map();
user.set(4, { id: 4, name: "Jane" }); //adds with id (4) as key
user.myMap.set(2, { id: 2, name: "Peter" }); // set user #2 to "Peter"
user.delete(3); //deletes user with id 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spreads:

Adding

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  4: { id: 4, name: "Jane" },
}
```

Removing id 2

```
let prevState = this.state;
let {"2": id, ...nextState} = prevState;
this.setState({
  ...nextState,
}
```

Changing id 2

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  2: {
    ...this.state["2"],
    name: "Peter",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` also accepts a function, which you might find more intuitive

```
function add( user ) {
  this.setState( users => {
    users[ user.id ] = user
    return users
  }
}

function remove( id ) {
  this.setState( users => {
    delete users[ id ]
    return users
}
```

These functions assume that your `state` object **is** your `users` object, if it is actually `state.users` then you'd have to pick `users` out, passing a function to `setState` will always be called passing the actual `state` object.

In this example `add` can also be used to amend, depending on your actual use-case you may want to create separate helpers.