# setState of an object - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have for example this :

```
this.state = {
      lang1: { name: 'Anglais', code: "en" },
      lang2: { name: 'Français', code: "fr" }
};
```

How can I setState the lang1.name? It doesn't work when I do:

```
this.setState({ lang1.name: "myExample" });
```

I'm new in React Native and I didn't understand that clearly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update object in React state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650570/how-to-update-object-in-react-state)

Comment: If you search this ques **how to update the object in state**, you will find so many results for the same ques, before asking once check whether that ques has been asked or not. check this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-do-i-update-state-item1-on-setstate-with-jsfiddle

Comment: I agree with @MayankShukla

Answer (score 11):

You can just do this. ... just adds exiting keys and then adds/overwrites new ones

```js
this.setState({
 lang1:{
  ...this.state.lang1,
  name: "myExample"
 }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

```
this.setState({
  lang1: {
    name: "myExample",
    code: this.state.lang1.code
  }
});
```

Comment: You should explain why this works instead of just giving a code-only answer. As it stands, this answer doesn't do much to help the OP or future visitors understand what's happening. You could also use the ES6 `...` spread operator to make your example more applicable to general scenarios

Comment: @Bojangles you are right and I think this answer is more helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/44562452/2674187, and about the reason, in js yo can't have object's key like this `lang1.name`, you can have `'lang1.name'` bit ist is not mine that it is the nested object, it just sting with dot

Comment: Yeah, before seeing your post I solved my solution. But thanks for the explanation, I understand more :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
this.setState((previousState) => {
  const lang1 = previousState.lang1
  return {...lang1, name: 'myExample'}
})
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Value is a parameter...

```
let data = this.state.objectState
data[prop] = value
this.setState({objectState: data})
```